# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar join y where?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

¡Hola a todos!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me sabría explicar la diferencia entre usar *where* y *join* en consultas que requieren datos de varias tablas como la siguiente?:

Por ejemplo, si quisiera conocer todas las películas en las que ha participado Xactor:

```
Select películas.título from actores inner join participaciones on actores.cod_actor=participaciones.cod_actor inner join películas on participaciones.cod_película=películas.cod_película where actores.nombre='xActor';

Select películas.título from actores, participaciones, películas where actores.nombre='xActor' and actores.cod_actor=participaciones.cod_actor and participaciones.cod_película=películas.cod_película;
```

¡Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!